# Vanishing gradient problem for recent stochastic recurrent neural networks

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, stochastic

Recently, I've found some papers about generative recurrent models. All have attached sub-networks like prior/encoder/decoder/etc. to well-known LSTM cell for composing an aggregation of new-type RNN cell.

I am just curious about whether the gradient vanishing/exploding happens or not to those new RNN cell. Isn't there any problem about that kind of combination?

#### References:

It seems like they all have similar pattern as mentioned above.

> [A Recurrent Latent Variable Model for Sequential Data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02216)
>
> [Learning Stochastic Recurrent Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7610)
>
> [Z-Forcing: Training Stochastic Recurrent Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05411)

#### Pseudocode

The pseudocode for recurrent architecture is below:

```
def new_rnncell_call(x, htm1):
    #prior_net/posterior_net/decoder_net is single layer or mlp each
    q_prior = prior_net(htm1) # prior step
    q = posterior_net([htm1, x]) # inference step
    z = sample_from(q) # reparameterization trick
    target_dist = decoder_net(z) # generation step
    ht = innerLSTM([z, x], htm1) # recurrent step
    return [q_prior, q, target_dist], ht
```

What concerns me are those naked weights outside of well-known LSTM (or GRU etc.) cell during processing bptt without any gating logic for activations as the weights inside LSTM. For me, this looks not similar to stacked-rnn layers or additional dense layers just to outputs.

Doesn't that have any gradient vanishing/exploding problem?

Comment: This is a great question, but I think it might fit better somewhere else, since it's really about statistics/machine learning, rather than a particular coding implementation...?

Comment: @gmds Thanks! As I am totally a newbie in stackoverflow, which category fits best for this question? Or you mean out-world of this site?

Comment: I think you might want to check out [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), which is a related site in the Stack Exchange network. All the best!